# How to override Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\TransactionDataBuilder class?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, cybersource

I want to pass the custom **REFERENCE_NUMBER** to CyberSource So, I tried to override the class Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\TransactionDataBuilder using below steps

> etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\TransactionDataBuilder" type="<vendor>\<module>\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\TransactionDataBuilder" />
```

> vendor\module\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\TransactionDataBuilder

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vender\Module\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder;

use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Helper\SubjectReader;
use Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface;

/**
 * Class TransactionDataBuilder
 */
class TransactionDataBuilder extends \Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\TransactionDataBuilder {

    /**
     * Builds ENV request
     *
     * @param array $buildSubject
     * @return array
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function build(array $buildSubject) {
        $paymentDO = SubjectReader::readPayment($buildSubject);

        return [
            self::TRANSACTION_UUID => $this->random->getRandomString(
                    self::RANDOM_LENGTH,
                    Random::CHARS_DIGITS
            ),
            self::REFERENCE_NUMBER => $this->getReferenceNumber($paymentDO->getPayment()),
            self::TRANSACTION_TYPE => $this->transactionType,
            self::AMOUNT => sprintf('%.2F', SubjectReader::readAmount($buildSubject)),
            self::CURRENCY => $paymentDO->getOrder()->getCurrencyCode(),
            self::LOCALE => substr($this->localeResolver->getLocale(), 0, 2)
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Returns reference number
     *
     * @param InfoInterface $payment
     * @return string
     */
    private function getReferenceNumber(InfoInterface $payment) {
        return 123456789;
    }

}
```

But it's not working in my case, I also tried to add code in **etc/frontend/di.xml** but, still the same result. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first of all, you should not use preferences to override classes, the preferences should be used only for interfaces https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/working-with-arch-bp.html.

There multiple ways of how to add custom `Reference Number` to request without using preference for `TransactionDataBuilder` class.

1. Implement custom Reference Number Data Builder and use Magento `TransactionDataBuilder` as a composition to override the `Reference Number`. And you need to override di.xml configurations for all classes which use this builder.
2. Implement custom Reference Number Data Builder and add it to all builder lists which are using `Reference Number`. As all builders return an array of data, the `Reference Number` value from Magento `TransactionDataBuilder` will be overwritten by your custom builder.

The second option is preferable as it easy to implement. You just need to create own custom builder:

```php
namespace Vendor\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder;

use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Request\BuilderInterface;

class ReferenceNumberDataBuilder implements BuilderInterface
{
    private const REFERENCE_NUMBER = 'reference_number';

    public function build(array $buildSubject)
    {
        return [
            self::REFERENCE_NUMBER => 'Your custom reference number'
        ];
    }
}
```

And add it to all classes, which use existing `Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\TransactionDataBuilder`:

```xml
<type name="CybersourcePaymentTokenRequest">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="builders">
            <item name="billing_address" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\BillingAddressDataBuilder</item>
            <item name="merchant" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\MerchantDataBuilder</item>
            <item name="cc" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\CcDataBuilder</item>
            <item name="token" xsi:type="string">CybersourceTokenTransactionBuilder</item>
            <item name="quote_data" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\MerchantSecureDataBuilder</item>
            <item name="reference_number" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\ReferenceNumber</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="CybersourcePaymentSaleRequest">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="builders">
            <item name="merchant" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\MerchantDataBuilder</item>
            <item name="payment_token" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\PaymentTokenBuilder</item>
            <item name="sale" xsi:type="string">CybersourceSaleTransactionBuilder</item>
            <item name="reference_number" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\ReferenceNumber</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="CybersourcePaymentAuthorizeRequest">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="builders">
            <item name="merchant" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\MerchantDataBuilder</item>
            <item name="payment_token" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\PaymentTokenBuilder</item>
            <item name="authorize" xsi:type="string">CybersourceAuthorizeTransactionBuilder</item>
            <item name="reference_number" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\ReferenceNumber</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

The mentioned classes use virtual types based on `Magento\Cybersource\Gateway\Request\SilentOrder\TransactionDataBuilder` that's why you need to re-configure them.

Comment: How to re-configure them? Can you please explain and add the code.

Comment: You need to add the code above into your custom module/extension in di.xml